# Why can GDB mask tracee's SIGKILL when attaching to the tracee

Tags: linux, gdb, signals, ptrace

The [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) man page says that **SIGKILL**  cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored. But I just observed that after attaching to a process with GDB, I can no longer send **SIGKILL** to that process (similarly, other signal cannot be delivered either). But after I detach and quit GDB, **SIGKILL** is delivered as usual.

It seems to me that GDB has blocked that signal (on behalf of the tracee) when attaching, and unblocked it when detaching. However, the [ptrace(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) man page says:

> While being traced, the tracee will stop each time a signal is delivered, even if the signal is being ignored.  (An exception is **SIGKILL**, which has its usual effect.)

So why does it behave this way? What tricks is GDB using?

Here is an trivial example for demonstration:

*1. test program*

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Simple error handling functions */

#define handle_error_en(en, msg) \
    do { errno = en; perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

struct sigaction act;

void sighandler(int signum, siginfo_t *info, void *ptr) {
    printf("Received signal: %d\n", signum);
    printf("signal originate from pid[%d]\n", info->si_pid);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Pid of the current process: %d\n", getpid());

    memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));

    act.sa_sigaction = sighandler;
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;

    sigaction(SIGQUIT, &act, NULL);

    while(1) {
        ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you try to kill this program using **SIGKILL** (i.e., using `kill -KILL ${pid}`), it will die as expected. If you try to send it **SIGQUIT** (i.e., using `kill -QUIT ${pid}`), those *printf* statements get executed, as expected. However, if you have attached it with GDB before sending it signal, nothing will happen:

```
$ ##### in shell 1 #####
$ gdb
(gdb) attach ${pid}
(gdb)
```

/* now that gdb has attached successfully, in another shell: */

```
$ #### in shell 2 ####
$ kill -QUIT ${pid}    # nothing happen
$ kill -KILL ${pid}    # again, nothing happen!
```

/* now gdb detached */

```
##### in shell 1 ####
(gdb) quit
```

/* the process will receive **SIGKILL** */

```
##### in shell 2 ####
$ Killed    # the tracee receive **SIGKILL** eventually...
```

FYI, I am using a CentOS-6u3 and `uname -r` result in `2.6.32_1-16-0-0`. My GDB version is: `GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-56.el6)` and my GCC version is: `gcc (GCC) 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-19.el6)`. An old machine...

Any idea will be appreciated ;-)

Comment: By "eventually", do you mean there is some delay between gdb detaching and the shell reporting that the process was killed?

Comment: I am quite certain GDB isn't using any tricks. You might have a broken kernel. I doubt your results will reproduce on a different system.

Comment: @EmployedRussian I am using ptrace(2) to implement similar functionality as GDB, but signal handling is becoming a mess because every time the tracee get that signal, it will get interrupt and the tracer will get notified spuriously...So I think GDB *is* using some tricks here. Why are you so sure? Can you clarify?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick no delay. There is no delay between gdb detaching and the shell reporting "killed". But I have not measured that pragmatically so it is hard to say whether there is any delay or not...

Comment: @EmployedRussian I try this with a 4.4.0 kernel (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) and it is the same, gdb is still masking those signals...

Comment: Oh, I see. Answer coming ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `$ ##### in shell 1 #####
>   $ gdb
>   (gdb) attach ${pid}
>   (gdb)`

The issue is that once GDB has attached to `${pid}`, the inferior (being debugged) process is *no longer running* -- it is *stopped*.

The kernel will not do *anything* to it until it is either continued (with the `(gdb) continue` command), or it is no longer being traced (`(gdb) detach` or `quit`).

If you issue `continue` (either before or after `kill -QUIT`), you'll see this:

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.
```

`kill -QUIT $pid` executed in another shell:

```
Program received signal SIGQUIT, Quit.
main (argc=1, argv=0x7ffdcc9c1518) at t.c:35
35      }

(gdb) c
Continuing.
Received signal: 3
signal originate from pid[123419]
```

`kill -KILL` executed in another window:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGKILL, Killed.
The program no longer exists.
(gdb)
```

Comment: Do you know which signal does GDB use to implement control transfer? By control transfer, I mean, after the tracee executing a function and return, which signal is generated so that GDB can wait*() on it and seize control again? It is not SIGTRAP though many people claim that ...

Comment: @walkerlala This is probably best asked as a separate question. I *do* know, but this comment field is too short ;-)

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47503036/what-signal-does-gdb-use-to-implement-control-transfer-between-tracee-and-tracer